# Emit click in other class in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got two Vue js classes that controls different html blocks (I have `script` tags for each, because I have server side template rendering)

```
 <li class="nav-item navbar-center" id="site-header">
       <a class="nav-link text-white h6" href="#" v-on:click="displayModal()">
          Log In / Sign Up
       </a>
  </li>

new Vue({
    el: '#site-header',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: {
        showModal: 'none',
    },
    methods: {
        displayModal() {
            if (this.showModal === 'none') {
                this.showModal = 'block';
            } else {
                this.showModal = 'none';
            }
        },

    },
})
```

And the second

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px" id="car_pre_reserve">
   <textarea v-model="messageSender" id="direct-message" placeholder="Your message here..."></textarea>
   <button v-on:click="sendMessage()" class="button" type="button">SEND MESSAGE</button>
</div>

    new Vue({
        el: '#car_pre_reserve',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data() {
            return {
                messageSender: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {

            sendMessage() {

                        this.messageStatusDisplay = 'block';
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            this.messageStatusDisplay = 'none';
                        }, 10000);

            },
        },
    });
```

The question is, can I call `displayModal()` from different vue class? And how to do this?

Comment: If the two components are not in a parent-child relationship, you could try to emit an event on the `$root` scope.

Comment: If you want to use two different apps on page, you can use variables in global window object to link each to other.
App 1 mounted: window.myOwnFunction = { popup1: this.sendMessage }
App 2 somewhere: someMethod() { window.myOwnFunction.popup1(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, that was pretty easy

I assigned class to variable

```
var header = new Vue({...})
```

and then in the second class just call `header.displayModal()`